# Hadoop Distribution File System

Tags: hdfs, filesplitting

I would like to modify the way an input file is split into blocks and stored in Hadoop Distributed File System.(example it splits the file based on block size but my application requires to split the file based on the file content).
 So i would like to know exactly the class which splits the file into blocks based on the block size Property of HADOOP.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are the abstractions for HDFS and InputSplits are the abstractions for MapReduce. By default, one HDFS block corresponds to one InputSplit which can be modified.

HDFS by default divides the blocks into exact 64MB blocks and might also split across record boundaries. It's upto the InputFormat to create InputSplits from the blocks of data in case of file input format. Each InputSplit will be processed by a separate mapper.

> example it splits the file based on block size but my application requires to split the file based on the file content

Think in terms of InputSplits and create a new InputFormat as per the application requirement. Here are some tutorials ([1](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat), [2](http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/) and [3](http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopInputFormat)) on creating a new InputFormat.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I intend to modify the hadoop source code. So i want to know how the control flows from one class to another in hdfs.<br>I would like to know the following:-<br>
1.The class which is invoked when we use the CopyFromLocal command in the command prompt to copy a file into hdfs.<br>
2.The class which creates objects for the class implementing the Mapper interface.<br>
3. The class which assigns the blocks to the list of datanodes(DatanodeDescriptor array) returned by the chooseTarget() function in the ReplicationTargetChooser class.